# program stops responding when I run for loop in C

Tags: c, arrays, prime-factoring

Logic: I am trying to loop from 3 to 100 and put all prime numbers in that range in an array. I do this by first putting 2 manually into the array. After that, I loop over all the numbers and if a number is not divisible by all the prime numbers I have added to the array, it is a prime. The logic itself is not really valid in my opinion but this is a homework problem and I need to do it the way the professor wants it to be done. 
So I try to loop and it gets to a point and the program just crashes. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    int primeNums_lessThan100[25] = {2}; //25 is the size here because there are only 25 prime numbers under 100.

    int primeNums_lessThan100_length = 1;
    for(int counter = 3 ; counter < 100 ; counter++)
    {
        printf("Entered here!\n");

        for(int array_idx = 0;  array_idx < primeNums_lessThan100_length ; array_idx++)
        {
            if(counter % primeNums_lessThan100[array_idx] != 0)
            {
                printf("Entered here, TOO!\n");
                primeNums_lessThan100[array_idx+1] = counter;
                primeNums_lessThan100_length++;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing wrong is to turn too early to Stackoverflow. Run your program in a debugger to see what it is doing - as a min it will tell you immediately which line is triggering the crash and then you can examine the variables. Ok, this comment is a bit cheeky but is meant to help you in the long run - learning to debug effectively is an essential skill.

Comment: @kaylum I admit that I have not tried that, I will try it now. Thank you.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: Once you get the debugger running I would suggest you break inside the `if` loop and then check all your array indices vs the current array length. Hopefully the problem may be more obvious once you do that.

Comment: The `else { continue; }` block is pointless in that if you omitted it, the code would still go to the next iteration of the loop.  That isn't the cause of your problem, though.

Comment: Rather than just `printf("Entered here!\n");`, print some useful information: `printf("Entered here! (counter = %d)\n", counter);`. Replace `printf("Entered here, TOO!\n");` with something like `printf("Entered here, TOO! (idx = %d, prime = %d, counter = %d)\n", array_idx, primeNums_lessThan_100[array_idx], counter);`. More significantly, though, you should know that if `counter` is evenly divisible by some prime number, it is not itself a prime number (so you can break the loop early), but a number is not prime unless it is not divisible by any of the primes — you need to rework the logic.

Comment: “I hadn’t tried that” - this is a bit of a shocker. As @kaylum commented, debugging is an absolutely essential skill for any programmer. Asking here should be a _last resort_. But if you _have_ to ask, after using a debugger, after trying working though the logic, etc. Then at least post some code that is a [mre] so people can paste it into a file and compile+run it _without having to add anything_. And make sure you test what you post in your question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That reminded me this cartoon:  [Why Logging Is So Important](http://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2015/10/18/why-logging-is-so-important) - Geeks & Pokes

Answer (score 1):

You have a basic error in your logic. It's not enough to find out the `counter` value is coprime with *some* previously found prime to determine `counter` is prime itself. You need to test it is coprime with *all* primes found.

Suppose `counter == 9` and you test it against the first item of your 'prime' numbers, which is `2`. The result of `9 % 2` is of course `1`, which is not equal zero and your program **adds `9` to the array as a prime number.** It happens even earlier for `counter == 4` — first you find out it is divisible by `2` and reiterate the loop to find out in the next step `4 % 3 != 0` and **add `4` to 'primes'.**

As a further result the array overflows (you put more numbers into it than you expected and declared; actually, you put every natural number to it, because each N greater than 2 is not divisible by (N-1)), which means you eventually write past the end of the array, thus triggering an Undefined Behavior.

That displays also a basic error in the design: you do not check your `array_idx` against the array size, which might allow you to handle the error in some civilized manner.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. comments in code explain what is being done
4. note use of `size_t` for numbers that will never be less than 0
5. Note that all prior prime values are checked against the `testPrime`
6. Note that when a prime is found, it is placed in the next available entry in the array: `primeNums[]

and now, the proposed code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>  // puts(), printf()

 // eliminate ''magic' numbers by giving them meaningful names
 //25 is the size here because there are only 25 prime numbers under 100
 #define MAX_PRIMES 25
 #define TEST_LIMIT 100

 int main( void )
 {
    // declare prime number array and init to 0
    int primeNums[ MAX_PRIMES ] = {0};

    // pre-set first prime number
    primeNums[0] = 2;

    // init number of primes found
    size_t primeCount = 1;

    // test all values of interest
    for( int testPrime = 3 ; testPrime < TEST_LIMIT ; testPrime++ )
    {
        // init 'prime' indicator, 1 means value is prime
        size_t Prime = 1;

        for( size_t prime_idx = 0;  prime_idx < MAX_PRIMES; prime_idx++ )
        {
            // check that array of prime values contains a valid prime
            if( primeNums[ prime_idx ] )
            {
                if( testPrime % primeNums[ prime_idx ] == 0 )
                {
                    // indicate not a prime number
                    Prime = 0;
                }
            }

            else
            { // else, all previously found prime numbers checked
                break;
            } // end if 
        } // end for each prime already found

        if( Prime )
        { // then test number was prime
            // update the array of primes
            primeNums[ primeCount ] = testPrime;

            // update the count of primes found
            primeCount++;
        }
    }

    // display the found primes
    for( size_t i = 0; i < primeCount; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d, ", primeNums[i] );
    }

    // assure the data gets displayed on the terminal before the program exits
    puts( "" );
}
```

a run of the proposed code results in:

2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97,

Comment: I apologize, I am very new with C. What does this line: 'if( primeNums[ array_idx ] )' mean?

Comment: That line, @new_learner, means the same as `if (primeNums[array_idx] != 0)`.  It’s a commonly used idiom in C.  You’ll often see conditions like `if (!pointer)` too, which means `if (!pointer != 0)` which is the same as `if (pointer == 0)` or “if the pointer is null”.